# How to find the derivative of a consumer surplus function in its original notation?

Tags: calculus, integration, economics

How do I find the derivative of this consumer surplus function with respect to $Q_0$? I know how to do it when I have function values but I'm not sure how to evaluate everything in its original notation.

$CS(Q_0)$ = $\int_{0}^{Q_0} P(Q)\,dQ$ -$P_0Q_0$

Where $P_0$ = $P(Q_0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We differentiate the given equation with respect to $Q_{0}$:

$$\frac{d}{dQ_{0}}CS(Q_{0}) = \frac{d}{dQ_{0}}\int_{0}^{Q_{0}}P(Q)\,dQ - \frac{d}{dQ_{0}}P_{0}Q_{0}.$$

Now, by the fundamental theorem of calculus we know that $$\frac{d}{dQ_{0}}\int_{0}^{Q_{0}}P(Q)\,dQ = P(Q_{0}).$$
Also, the product rule tells us that
$$-\frac{d}{dQ_{0}}P_{0}Q_{0} = -\frac{dP_{0}}{dQ_{0}}Q_{0} - P_{0}\frac{dQ_{0}}{dQ_{0}}.$$
Because we know that $P_{0} = P(Q_{0})$ we get
$$-\frac{d}{dQ_{0}}P_{0}Q_{0} = -\frac{dP(Q_{0})}{dQ_{0}}Q_{0} - P_{0}\frac{dQ_{0}}{dQ_{0}} = -P'(Q_{0})Q_{0} - P_{0}.$$

All together, then, we get
$$CS'(Q_{0}) = P(Q_{0}) - P'(Q_{0})Q_{0} - P_{0} = -P'(Q_{0})Q_{0}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got this. Can I kindly ask for a small explanation?

Comment: Note: I'm getting $P(Q_0)-P(Q_0)(Q_0)$ - what am I missing?

Comment: @squishymath I've edited my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @DMcMor  - I was missing product rule I understand now.